# How long does it take for the University to send decisions post dept recommendations?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters

I applied for a Masters in the first week of December. I haven't heard back about the decision yet. After emailing the head of the department, he told me that the department's recommendations have been sent to the University and I should hear about the decision shortly. What could this mean?

The Program's assistant previously told me that the department is running late with evaluations. Any insight would be helpful here!

Comment: _What could this mean?_ Exactly what it says, these things almost never have a hidden subtext. See also: [How long does it usually take to hear back for academic positions? Why haven't I heard back and when should I follow up?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/193773)

Answer (score 1):

Nobody can give you a more definite answer than the "Program Assistant" here, especially since you do not name the department to which you applied. All universities have procedures for admissions that they follow, but admissions to graduate programs in the US are more varied. It sounds like there was a glitch in their admission procedure this year, but we do not know their work-flow.

This question cannot be answered, even if we would now the program to which you applied. We cannot even speculate why the chair could not give you better feed-back.

Comment: Previously the same head of department mentioned she would consider my application (to supervisor me in the program) Do they typically not disclose if you have been or not been recommended?

Comment: That would depend on the rules at the institution. If a department head promises you something, but then the university decides that they cannot admit you, you could cause trouble. So, department heads either are or are told to not make promises.