# No follow-up after pre-employment tasks

Tags: job-search, interview, bioinformatics

I applied for a bioinformatician position at a university lab. Talked to the PI twice and was assigned a total of two tasks, one after each Zoom call.

After I turned in the second task the PI replied they had to catch up with a deadline. And said she’ll get in touch with me if she has questions about my results. That was last Tuesday. The deadline has past last week and it’s Tuesday evening now. So it’s been a week since we last contacted.

Does it sound OK to send a follow-up email tomorrow? I don’t want to sound pushy, but I’d really love to know if she decides to hire me or not. I’m on OPT so I’ll have to leave some time to switch jobs.

Or are there any other suggestions? Please feel free to leave them below. I don’t quite know how people in academia handle these things.

Thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How long does it usually take to hear back for academic positions? Why haven't I heard back and when should I follow up?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/193773/how-long-does-it-usually-take-to-hear-back-for-academic-positions-why-havent-i)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure precisely what OPT will entail for your personal situation. The general rule, however, is only to contact a potential employer about your application status if you need to make a time-sensitive decision (say within 2-3 weeks) and that the outcome of the application would influence your decision.

It sounds to me like you may be in this situation, but it's not entirely clear.

Comment: Thanks M! That’s a good point. I do agree that one should only follow up when they’re running out of time, in general.