# What can be the status of my postdoc position application?

Tags: postdocs

I applied for a postdoc position in the US, the position is not entirely related to my work but there is significant overlap with my experience and expertise. I heard back from the PI with in a week and they asked me to make a 30 minute presentation for their lab. I did well and they were indirectly offering me the position during a brief meeting.
This was more than a month back, the PI is replying to my mails and enquiries and I was also asked to submit the letter of recommendation from my mentors. I thought the process will pickup pace from there, but I have not been offered the post officially. I even proposed a research plan to work on if I can get the position, they were appreciative of it. Recently, I had to give another interview with a senior collaborator of the PI and the discussion was about generic stuff like my interest in the university, the country and nothing about my work experience or aspirations. They told they will get back to me in a week's time but I am feeling very disheartened with the way things are progressing.
What can be the possible status of my application? I feel that I might not be their first choice and I am scared I will be rejected after all these weeks. I had to let go off another potential postdoc position anticipating this will work out. I feel stuck and helpless.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [How long does it usually take to hear back for academic positions? Why haven't I heard back and when should I follow up?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/193773) Even if the question isn't an exact match, the answer (particularly about the futility of trying to guess what's really happening) is directly applicable.

Answer (score 3):

If they knew they were not going to offer you the job, they would tell you this and stop wasting their own time (and yours) on various interview steps.

If they knew they were going to offer you the job, they would tell you this and stop wasting their own time (and yours) on various interview steps.

The status of your application is "unknown". Worrying about it will not help the status. Because you don't have a job secured, you should continue to apply to other positions. Once you have accepted an offer, you can mostly stop applying to other positions, but may still want to continue the search process for another job after the next one ends.