# Have you encountered a prolonged silence from a potential supervisor following a canceled interview, leaving you uncertain about their decision?

Tags: phd, interview

I contacted a prospective supervisor expressing my interest in collaborating with them. After an initial interview, they scheduled a more technical follow-up discussion, but it was canceled due to an unforeseen issue on their end. Following this, I haven't received any further communication for over two weeks. Could this indicate that they've moved forward and hired another candidate?

Comment: Have you tried to follow up? This can be a very busy time if it's end of semester/finals for the supervisor's institution.

Comment: It could indicate a lot of things or nothing at all. And other people's experience is no indicator of what might happen in yours. After two weeks you can ask for an update, of course.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How long does it usually take to hear back for academic positions? Why haven't I heard back and when should I follow up?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/193773/how-long-does-it-usually-take-to-hear-back-for-academic-positions-why-havent-i)

Comment: I vote to reopen. This is a very useful question, and the alleged duplicate is specifically about a job interview. Here the scenario is different.

Comment: Baeed on the phrases "potential supervisor" and "hired another candidate," I'm guessing that this is a job interview situation. In any case, there's nothing we can add to what the answer to the duplicate question says; no one on the internet knows what is going through the supervisor's head.

Comment: @cag51, here the scenario is slightly different: the interview was *cancelled* and from that point communication lost. Hence, the answers in the alleged duplicate are not adequate here. Here the situation is very clear: send a reminder, and if you don't get a timely answer you are being deliberately avoided. That's not the case in a job interview where no answer should be expected due to legal reasons, and waiting for other candidates' offer acceptance.

Answer (score 2):

This is a general and familiar question: *what should be inferred from a prolonged silence from one party.*

The answer is quite straightforward in most cases.

1. If you have not even *tried to contact* the silent party and remind them about the imminent decision, asking them to reply, then there is **absolutely nothing** that can be inferred from the silence.
2. If on the other hand, you've reminded the silent party about the imminent issue, and they still haven't replied for at least three days, then **chances are high they are avoiding answering you on purpose**. What is the cause of this probable intentional avoidance though is unknown (it can be dis-interest, indecisiveness, being occupied with other issues, trying to delay decision, etc.).